# Using linked spans in textview

Tags: java, android, hyperlink, textview, spannable

I have a textview created in a class B programaticly. When class A calls it.

It adds text say "I went to the shop" and i need the word "the" to be a link. This i have done using this in CLASS B

```
sb.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(Word), start, start+Word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

which is calling the class MyClickableSpan

```
public class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan {
private String word;

public MyClickableSpan(String word) {
    this.word = word;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View widget) {

    Log.d("Spaannnned",word);

}
}
```

So when this link is clicked it is showing up in my log.

But I need it to run a function in Class A and pass in the word.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a click listener interface to your span:

```
public class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan {
public interface SpanClickListener
{
     public void onSpanClicked(View widget, MyClickableSpan span);
}
private String word;
private SpanClickListener clickListener;

public MyClickableSpan(String word, SpanClickListener listener) {
    this.word = word;
    clickListener = listener;
}
public String getWord() { return word; }

@Override
public void onClick(View widget) {
        Log.d("Spaannnned",word);
        if (clickListener != null) clickListener.onSpanClicked(widget, this);
    }
}
```

Then, in your activity:

```
MyClickableSpan span = new MyClickableSpan("Hello!", new MyClickableSpan.SpanClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onSpanClicked(View widget, MyClickableSpan span)
           {
                Toast.makeText(context, span.getWord(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           }
        };
....
//add your span to the Spannable or whatever you want.
```

Comment: But wouldnt with this method have to set the span in class a? Whic at the moment isnt an ooption

Comment: Well, if you want to call something in class A, then you must somehow supply a reference to instance of A to class B anyway. Unless you are using a message bus or message queue of some sort, which I don't think is the case.

Comment: Just create an instance of SpanClickListener in A, then supply it to the class B, which will use it during creation of spans.

Comment: Thank you, i got most of it using your idea. As class B creating the span I also got it to save them in an array list. Then in class A I use a for loop telling it the activity. Then implement mySpanListener and it seems to work. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Supply your instance of "Class A" to the constructor of `MyClickableSpan`, save it in a data member, and use that from your `onClick()` method.

Or, use an [event bus like Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/), to have onClick() send out a message that "Class A" subscribes to.

Comment: Otto looks interesting.. will look tomorrow. Unfortunately cllass b where the span is set. Does not know about class a.